# React Input with disabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I have an input with the disabled boolean propagated from the props.  I've found that with that disabled variable being set, even when it's true I cannot type into the input.  I can, however, type into the input if I hold the mouse down on it and keep it down as I type.

This happens when I render the component as both controlled and uncontrolled.

The only way to fix it is to either removing `disabled` or setting `disabled={false}` -- but I need it to be variabled.

This is my input:

```
  class DashboardWidgetTitle extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {};
      this.state.title = props.widget.getTitle();
    }

    render () {
      return <input className="title"
                    value={this.state.title}
                    disabled={!this.props.isEditMode}
                    onChange={this._onInputChange.bind(this)}/>
    }

    _onInputChange(e) {
      logit("input change");
      this.setState({title: e.target.value});
    }

  }
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Extra info --

- This is used in a widget within an implementation of [ReactGridLayout](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout).
- The component is rendered by a widget that is rendered by the implementation of react grid layout, the "dashboard".  That Dashboard has `isEditMode` as a state that's changed externally via a toggle in Angular (we use React within Angular).
- If I switch tabs and come back, the focus remains.  Otherwise whenever I type a letter, the input becomes unfocused.
- The input isn't disabled when it shouldn't be, it just has focusing issues -- however removing the `disabled` attribute or setting it as a static variable, the issue doesn't remain.
- When I switch the disabled toggle to be `isEditMode` rather than `!isEditMode`, everything works.  It seems to be there's an onclick on the draggable/resizable portion of the ReactGridLayout that's causing some issues.

Comment: can you show the code where you render `DashboardWidgetTitle`

Comment: Yeah, it's fairly simple:

    `<DashboardWidgetTitle widget={this.props.widget} 
                                           isEditMode={this.props.isEditMode}/>`


the `isEditMode` is set 2 levels up as a state object.  It isn't being changed.

Comment: It just looks like your `isEditMode` is not being passed down correctly.  I would log it's value on render.  My guess is that it's undefined (not passed) and `!undefined` is `true`.

Comment: Is this what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/91532/

Comment: yeah that was my first thought too.  The input doesn't have the `disabled` attribute at all when it shouldn't.  The input does allow focus, in this case, just not a change.

The weirdest part is I can get it to work if I type as I hold down the mouse on the input.  I'm

Comment: Per your last comment about the mouse, I have to think your input is losing focus on render (and as a result you cant type in it). Just for SnG's add `key="myinput"` to give it a static key...

Comment: The component is not re-rendered when that toggle button is clicked in your `Angular` app. Make sure the parent component of `DashboardWidgetTitle` gets re-rendered with your expected props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was described right here: https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/issues/615

My own fault of poor research.